# Java Akka with RabbitMQ

Tags: java, apache-camel, rabbitmq, akka

Am I missing something here? I've seen that in Scala you can provide a message body and a routing key and send to an exchange, also using basicPublish in Java the message body and a routing key can be provided, but when using a Producer actor (extends UntypedProducerActor) I can send a message with the routing key used when the producer was created

```
    ActorRef producer = context().actorOf( prototypeProducer.props( uriBuilder.getDownlinkRabbitmqUri() ) );
```

but to send to the same exchange with another routing key I can't see any other way than create another actor.

I'd like to use a single producer but change the routing key dynamically is there any way?